# Connecting to db2 from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, db2, database-connection

I know that while connecting .net to oracle, you can attach dll's and run the program, can we do the same with db2? if so, then what are the dlls and where can i find them? i've tried connecting ibm.data.db2.dll (downloaded from net) but vs is giving a error saying it may not be valid build for vs.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install at least the IBM Data Server Runtime client appropriate for your DB2 version and, optionally, Visual Studio plug-ins from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878